# A problem on rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I am using ROS hydro and learning the basis of rviz, following the tutorial in http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes. But nothing displays on rviz. In Global Options -> Fixed Frame there is only the default option "map", but no "/my_frame" as shown in the link above. I source the setup.bash and set the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in every termial. Could you please give me some suggestions? Many thanks.

The cpp file is exactly same as shown in the link. The CMakeList is shown below.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(using_markers)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
roscpp
visualization_msgs
)

catkin_package()

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(basic_shapes src/basic_shapes.cpp)

target_link_libraries(basic_shapes ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

I also add add_dependencies(basic_shapes using_markers_generate_messages_cpp), but no result either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147211/a-problem-on-rviz/) by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on 2014-04-01**:
i think you have to type the frame name

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-01**:
Just to confirm, have you run catkin_make, and is the basic_shapes node is running?

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-04-02**:
Hi guys, thanks for your help.
@Sai I type the"/my_frame", but it does not work either.
@ahendrix I run catkin_make, but what is the node of basic_shapes?

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-02**:
You are trying a command rosrun rviz rviz, aren't you. If you can't look at /my_frame in Fixed Frame in Rviz, /my_frame isn't registered. I think so.

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-04-02**:
@ken_in_JAPAN thank you. I think you are right. But could you please tell me how to register the frame? I am nooby to ros. so.. Many thanks.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-02**:
At first, you should try a command rosrun tf view_frames. More detail are described on a web site.
http://wiki.ros.org/tf.
If you look at frames.pdf, you have to decide where you put /my_frame. After that, it is better for you to refer static_transform_publisher on same web. I think so.

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-04-02**:
Hi @Ken_in_JAPAN thank you. I am trying to do it!

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-07-06**:
did someone get exact solution for this, i followed the instruction in the ans below also but didnt worked. what is exact solution?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-06**:
This **is** an exact solution; it lists the exact commands to run, the order to run them in, and shows how to configure rviz. If you're having trouble following these instructions please read [how to ask smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and then ask a new question.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-07-06**:
ok i got the answer, what i was doing wrong was after not seeing the /my_frame title inside the fixed_frame topic, i was not getting the output, i should write the topic /my_frame inside that fixed_frame my self manually, i was confused cas i was not seeing /my_frame in that box when i clicked it
di

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could do that!
At first, I typed next command to install basic_shapes on my computer.

```
$ catkin_make install
</pre>
After that, I tried following on terminal.
<pre>
$ roscore
```

On another terminal

```
$ rosrun using_markers basic_shapes
</pre>
On third terminal
<pre>
$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 map my_frame 100
```

On last terminal

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz
```

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1